# GUI Err MeshManager.cc:131 Invalid mesh filename extension

Tags: blender, mesh, gazebo-simu, skeletal-mesh

I'm getting the following errors using a [simple sdf file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/gazebo9/worlds/animated_box.world) that I get from the tutorial of animating a box:

```
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [GUI] [Err] [MeshManager.cc:131] Invalid mesh filename extension[tutorial/worlds/__default__]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [GUI] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:1027] Actor skin mesh [tutorial/worlds/__default__] not found.
```

I tried adding armature to the box in blender but with no success.

I'm using Gazebo garden on ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not possible to use collada object in modern gazebo, unless if it has a mesh with skeletal animation. instead you can use [trajectory follower](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/trajectory_follower.sdf).